# JSON Data not appear in another computer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I tried to fetch JSON data from the API with http://localhost:3030/get/articles and the data was successfully displayed on my reactjs, but when I tried on another computer the JSON data did not appear, I used axios to get the JSON data. Has anyone ever experienced or been able to help my problem?

Comment: you are using local host so you can only access this url to the same pc not in another pc

Comment: try this http://localhost.run/

Comment: how to use this application localhost.run @illiteratewriter

Comment: localhost means that its only accessible on that computer....other computers cannot access it

Answer (score 1):

Localhost is just a local server built on your own computer machine. Which can be used to host website locally for testing it.

If you want your project to be accessible from other computer, you should install your project on a web server with registered domain name pointing to this web server.

Answer (score 1):

Localhost is a local server built on your own computer to development and testing. so if you want to access your application another users, you should published to server side computer or cloud.

Comment: What is your question here? If you publish your product you should deploy it into the public server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're accessing `localhost` which means the local machine.

When you try to access `localhost` in your web browser, you're basically saying `this computer`. If you do it on the machine where you develop your application then it will work but on another computer it wont.

A solution to access your JSON from another machine could be to use the IP of the machine that provide the JSON instead of the `localhost` keyword.

Like this: `http://IP_OF_THE_MACHINE:3030/get/articles`.

E.g.
`http://192.168.10.12:3030/get/articles`

You can get the machine's IP by typing `ipconfig` (for Windows) in a **Command Prompt**.

You can use a **DNS entry** or **edit** the **C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts** file on Windows to avoid typing the IP address everytime.

Comment: Yes, maybe if using IP data will be displayed, but if there are many computers running my react apps, will the json data also appear? @Teasel

Comment: How do you generate your json data? Is there an API running on a computer? As long as you use the IP it should work, unless computers are in a different network then you should look for a DNS entry

Answer (score 0):

You can run `ssh -R 80:localhost:8080 ssh.localhost.run`. where `8080` is your port number. Yours should be along the lines `ssh -R 80:localhost:3030 ssh.localhost.run` since `3030` is your port number.

When you run this in your terminal you will get a message `Connect to http://dummydata.com.localhost.run`. Go to that link and basically you'll get your stuff online.

Comment: how can i deploy my json API? I'm still a beginner and I use nodejs express to make this APi ?

Comment: open the terminal run `ssh -R 80:localhost:3030 ssh.localhost.run` and go the url that is shown in the terminal